# Is there a way to train data on imprecise target ? What kind of loss should be use?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am currently trying to train my neural network with an imprecise target. Basically my target data is a curve but I want to fit and approach the trend of the curve considering that it is not the ground truth one but an approximation with certain percentage of confidence.

Is there any loss function to take into account the confidence on a curve we have ? What could be a way to let the neural net know that the target is imprecise ?

I have tried to implement the loss in the part 3.1 of this article without any success (link here : https://jcsadeghi.github.io/assets/papers/neunet.pdf )

Let me know if you have any idea

Comment: You could try a loss function that does not penalize for predictions within some margin of error of the target, and this margin could be unique for each example

Comment: Another option is to weigh the loss function by confidence. This way, samples with high confidence should have a higher weight on the loss function which makes the model pay more attention to high confidence samples.